# error al instalar scikit-image en python después de instalar visual 14.0

Tags: python, visual-studio

el problema es que no puedo instalar scikit-image primero salio el error requiere visual 14.0 al instalar tools visual y volver a intentar me dio el siguiente error.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\winrt" /Tcskimage\_shared\geometry.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.obj
  geometry.c
  c:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include\pyconfig.h(222): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\luis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\winrt" /Tcskimage\_shared\geometry.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.obj" failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya vi que no puedes instalar scikit-image ni scipy en windows de la manera tradicional tienes que descargar distribuciones no oficiales dejo el link 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image

```
pip install scikit_image-0.13.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install scipy-1.0.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```